# Accepting my own answer

Tags: discussion, support

I finally figured out an answer to a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/enabled-option-for-slider-in-manipulate-not-updating-dynamically) I posed more than two weeks ago. It's the only answer. Should I accept it? That is, is it good etiquette for a person to accept an own-answer?

Comment: Good question.  Yes, it's entirely appropriate, especially if it is a complete solution and the matter is resolved.  (BTW it will not bump your own answer to the top of the page as it will other answers.)

Comment: as others have said, please do. it's not bad manners (especially as there are no other answers!) and it's useful for anybody who might run across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if you believe that your solution is the best one of all solutions, it should be the one you accept.  (However if you based it on one or more answer given by others, or it's not significantly different from existing answers, you can simply describe it in an edit to the question.)

On StackExchange sites we try to make questions and answers useful *for future visitors* as well as the original poster.  Let this be one of your guiding principles when posting here.

More reading:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: There are no other solutions that I am aware of. I believe both my question and my answer are in accordance with the principle you state. Please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: I just did that.

Comment: @m_goldberg I tried to make the answer a bit more general, but if there are no other answers, and you do find a working solution yourself, then there's even more reason to post it as an answer and accept it.  Personally I appreciate it when people take the time to come back and describe their solutions, especially since writing it up might take quite a bit of time

Comment: @Szabolcs I posted a couple of weeks ago the following question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/restricted-accumulation-of-values. The task was to improve a formula in terms of speed or elegance. Since none of the answers improved my formula I guess mine is the best (which sounds kind of arrogant to me). So shall I copy my formula and post it as an answer to my question?